# Content Query Web Part not displaying image correctly

Tags: content-query-web-part, site

I was changing columns and content types to create a custom area in a page layout so to add a summary area on the article page  Somehow I changed one of the content types and now content query web part will not move the image to the right side and title is showing on the bottom.  My question is anybody know how to revert the site content and site columns?